# create trigger to alter multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

i have n tables,

and each table share a common column 'COLX'. And each table's COLX column can have independent values in that column, but when someone alters value in Main table T's COLX, each table's corresponding COLX value must be updated with new value in T's COLX.

I can only write trigger for one table only, how to write this for n tables?

Comment: That is redundant. Why even have that columns if they are all the same as in the main table?

Comment: not in my case, they are not same until someone alters in main table T. Before any update in main table T, each sub tables can have different values in that column COLX.

Answer (score 0):

COLXCascade your triggers through the tables,

table1 will trigger updates to table2,
table2 can then run triggers to affect table3

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (COLX INT NOT NULL,
                 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (id INT, COLX INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (COLX) REFERENCES table1(COLX)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: Can you tell me a brief example of trigger cascade?

Comment: i've added an example for you.